# Do all international browsers display the exception STACK in English or in the browser's native language?

Tags: javascript, exception, browser, internationalization, cross-browser

I am wondering if all international browsers produce the exception STACK in english or in the native language.

**I am NOT asking about translating a web page. I am asking about a different version of the browser language where everything about the browser is in the other language including the menus, etc.**

For example in the English Chrome browser I get an exception stack like this:

```
myState.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stack')
    at new MyStateError (myState.js:10:17)
    at createState (myState.js:22:11)
    at statetest.html:16:23
```

Will it be the same for a French or Spanish browser? Or will the French version look like this:

```
myState.js:10 Non capturé TypeError : Impossible de lire les propriétés d'une valeur indéfinie (lecture de 'stack')
    à new MyStateError (myState.js:10:17)
    à créerÉtat (myState.js:22:11)
    à statetest.html:16:23
```

I don't have a second machine on which I can install a different browser. Can someone that has a non-English install of a browser let me know what they get. **(Again I am not concerned with page translations, I am looking for someone that has a full Non-English version installed on an OS that is not English)**

You can run these lines of code in Dev Tools to find out:

```
let a = new Error();
console.log(a.stack)
```

Comment: you don't need a second machine. You can change the browser language in Preferences.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop for how to do it.

Comment: But the simple answer is that they translate most messages.

Comment: Changing the Preferred language in settings is not the same as setting the default language of the browser. I need everything about the browser to be in a different language and not just the web pages. I am trying changing the default language of Mac OS to see if this will let me see it.